# How to print something, if a test has failed in Google Test?

Tags: c++, googletest

I have some sophisticated test with a lot of `ASSERT()` and `EXPECT()`. The test checks some properties about a string, say command-line. And I want to print this string in case the test has failed in any of possible ways.

I don't want:

- Put `<< string` at every `ASSERT()`.
- See the string more than once, in case of multiple failures with `EXPECT()`.

I want to do something like this:

```
TEST(MyTest, Test1) {
  ...
  if (HAS_FAILED()) { std::cout << string << std::endl; }
}
```

Comment: Does that work?  If not, what does it do?  What do you want it to do?

Comment: @DrewDormann actually, there is no macro with exactly the same name - and I don't know any other macro with the same functionality. The question is about some advanced knowledge of gtest - as I see it.

Comment: When I read you question, it's difficult to understand what the question is.  I don't see a question anywhere, I just see "I want this".  And I'm not sure what that means.   Are you asking how to write `IS_FAILED`?

Comment: @DrewDormann, hmm, I thought that the exact question goes in the header: `How to print something, if a test has failed in Google Test?` - I can put the same line in the end of my description, will it make the question more clear? - I believe, that my question requires some extra context to be understood and answered.

Comment: @DrewDormann - I'm asking if there is some kind of mechanism, that allows me to print something, if my test has failed in any way. AFAIK, the `ASSERT()` has `return` statement inside, so it's not that simple like write my own macro - there may be some internal gtest mechanism, or may be not. Or may be there is some technique, that I can't figure out by myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `HasFatalFailure()`.

```
TEST(FooTest, Bar) {
Subroutine();
// Aborts if Subroutine() had a fatal failure.
if (HasFatalFailure())
    return;
// The following won't be executed.
...
}
```

More details [here](http://code.google.com/p/googletest/wiki/AdvancedGuide#Checking_for_Failures_in_the_Current_Test)